# keyboard input in calculator in c# and managing the cursor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am making a calculator. I want it to take input from the keyboard too. this is a portion of my code. The problem is that at the second input from keyboard the + sign doesn't go, it appends with the "+" sign and while input from button click it doesn't show + sign. and tell me is it right to make a function for both button click and key press or i should make separate for each? and how to manage cursor in textbox?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        yourArithmeticOperation = true;                 //Enable Arithmetic button click
        yourEqual = true;                               //Enable Equal button click
        if (yourNumberControl)                          //check number button to append or start new
        {
            if (yourControlClick)                       //check click button enabled or not
            {
                textBox1.Text += "1";                   //append no.

            }
            else
                return;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = "1";                        //clear textbox and put new no.
            yourNumberControl = true;                    //Enable Number button click
        }


    }

private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Add)
        {
            add();
        }

    }

    private void add()
    {
        yourEqual = false;                              //Disable equal button
        yourNumberControl = true;                       //enable number button
        if (yourArithmeticOperation)                    //check Arithmetic button
        {
            num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = "";
            equal = "+";
            yourArithmeticOperation = false;            // disable arithmetic operator
        }
        else                                            //change the arithmeetic sign
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            equal = "+";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you pressing Key.Add (the big + on the numpad) or Key.OemPlus (the key next to backspace)?

Comment: Key.Add(the big + on the numpad)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want to do, but does putting `e.Handled = true;` before the call to `add();` in `textBox1_KeyDown` fix your problem?

Comment: nope.
let me describe in more detail and in parts.
first i input some number in textbox and while pressing + the no. is stored in     num1      and the         textbox.Text="+"        and while entering the 2nd operand the digit are appended after + in textbox. What i wanna do is to omit "+" sign in textbox after entering the first digit of 2nd operand.

Comment: Are you saying you basically want it to work like the Windows calc.exe works? The reason you are not getting much attention for this is because this is not a http://sscce.org/ . This is kind of an unwieldy way to solve the problem you are solving, and the code is not very clear. My advice is to make it work first with buttons or text, then add the other part. Doing things like managing the cursor/placement of text in this textbox is a very messy way of handling this.

Comment: i hav built well functioning basic calculator that works on only on button. And now i want to upgrade it to work on keyboard input. Im beginner and this is my first app.

Comment: any way... have u solved it out @umuieme ?